# How necessary is # in href for jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, href

Sometimes when you run a piece of jQuery, you put a # symbol in the HREF attribute, but why? I do understand what # means, but i'm asking if you have this `<a href="#" id="runScript">Run</a>`

why would you actually put a # in the href and return false, could you just leave it blank and achieve the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving the `href` attribute blank will not accomplish the same as stopping the default action. A blank value may either be percieved by the browser as a non-value, causing it to render the element as a bookmark instead of a link, or as a link to the same page, causing a reload.

The value `#` is just an URL that causes a minimum of disturbance if the script fails to suppress the default action. If the script ends with an error, the default action will still kick in.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no javascript on the browser, clicking the link will not load a new page.

Answer (score 2):

If you leave it blank, some quirk browser might not style the `<a>` as a click-able link. That's probably the only reason we need that `#`.

A better thing to do with `href` however is link to a page that achieve the same function w/o script, e.g. `<a href="/new" id="load-new-btn">New Items</a>`

Answer (score 1):

As the above posts said, it won't be styled as a clickable link. But instead you can just do:

```
a{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

in the CSS.

Comment: it helped me,  <a >something</a> and giving it pointer by css

Answer (score 0):

Both variants of this are evil. For example they fail for "Open in new Tab". You should use `#enoughInfoToLoadThePage` instead. Or perhaps an url which works without javascript.

And you might even want to use [this technique](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) to make them crawlable by google.

Answer (score 0):

if you leave href as "" (blank), the same page which you are on will load the page again.

return false or # makes sure the page is not loaded .

Comment: do you mean return false AND #?

Comment: the href can be either of "#" or "javascript:return:false" to make sure the page is not loaded again when clicked on the link

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to note is that if you have no href attribute the  won't visually act like a normal link. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/7DKhk/).

Comment: I think you misunderstood, i'm asking why put a # not the whole href attribute

Comment: oh sorry about that... then I'd go with Sairam Kunala's response